# Spring Security: WebSecurityConfig class `antMatchers(...).permitAll()` not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm adding a new endpoint to my Spring application. I am using Spring Security the check the roles from the JWT and grant access. However, right now I am not even checking on the roles, I am permitting all to use the URL. I already had three endpoints `POST` that works as expected. The fourth endpoint `GET` method is where I am having issues.

Please check the below configuration and let me know if am I missing something.

***Disclaimer**: I erase beans and dependency injection objects from this config class to show where I am having the issue.*

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.mywebsite.framework.security", "com.mywebsite.utility"})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(crossPlatformFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // WORKS AS EXPECTED
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mywebsite/v1/something_1").permitAll()
                // WORKS AS EXPECTED
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mywebsite/v1/something_2").permitAll()
                // WORKS AS EXPECTED
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mywebsite/v1/something_3").permitAll()
                // NOT WORKING, RETURNS 401 Http Code
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/mywebsite/v1/something_4").permitAll() //TODO: Not Working, returning 401
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests();
    }
}
```

I just added the fourth `.antMatchers()`, which is not working not sure why, is returning 401. The first three `.antMatchers()` works without any issue.

Has anyone had the same issue as me?

I am just adding one more endpoint as GET.

***Logs:***

```
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession 167   -- No HttpSession currently exists 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext 117   -- No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created. 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 157   -- Request 'GET /mywebsite/v1/something_4' doesn't match 'POST /logout' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 157   -- Request 'GET /mywebsite/v1/something_4' doesn't match 'POST /login' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 7 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 8 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 177   -- Checking match of request : '/mywebsite/v1/something_4'; against '/logout' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest 95   -- saved request doesn't match 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 11 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 12 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter 100   -- Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@bddba886: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 13 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' 
o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter 124   -- Requested session ID 17C1F2C0B0E165F7DCF87E14CDB0F6DA is invalid. 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 14 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /mywebsite/v1/something_4 at position 15 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation 219   -- Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /mywebsite/v1/something_4; Attributes: [authenticated] 
o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired 348   -- Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@bddba886: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased    .decide 66   -- Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@56253eba, returned: -1 
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException 180   -- Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    ...........
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 167   -- Request '/mywebsite/v1/something_4' matched by universal pattern '/**' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.*']] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 177   -- Checking match of request : '/mywebsite/v1/something_4'; against '/**/favicon.*' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 210   -- Ignoring 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 231   -- Did not match any media types 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[multipart/form-data], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 210   -- Ignoring 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 231   -- Did not match any media types 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[text/event-stream], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 210   -- Ignoring 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 231   -- Did not match any media types 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 73   -- All requestMatchers returned true 
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest 61   -- DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/v1/something_4] 
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication 211   -- Calling Authentication entry point. 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence 78   -- Trying to match using AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 210   -- Ignoring 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 231   -- Did not match any media types 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 69   -- Did not match 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence 78   -- Trying to match using OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher  .matches 65   -- Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher  .matches 65   -- Trying to match using AndRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 66   -- Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 223   -- text/html .isCompatibleWith */* = true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher.matches 51   -- matches = false 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AndRequestMatcher .matches 69   -- Did not match 
o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher  .matches 65   -- Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5bb661e0, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 203   -- httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*] 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 207   -- Processing */* 
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher.matches 216   -- isEqualTo true 
o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher  .matches 68   -- matched 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence 83   -- Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@3d3e9163 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence 78   -- Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest] 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence 91   -- No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@4da27f00 
o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter  .writeHeaders 169   -- Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2784c3cd 
tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext 346   -- SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext 346   -- SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter 119   -- SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession 179   -- HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext 117   -- No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@591f2d03. A new one will be created. 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 157   -- Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' 
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches 157   -- Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 7 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 8 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest .propertyEquals 359   -- pathInfo: both null (property equals) 
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest .propertyEquals 359   -- queryString: both null (property equals) 
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest .propertyEquals 383   -- requestURI: arg1=/mywebsite/v1/something_4; arg2=/error (property not equals) 
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest 95   -- saved request doesn't match 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 11 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 12 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter 100   -- Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@bddba886: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EC7B42A8FB862A6AEBDC3CD49485BEE9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 13 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 14 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 328   -- /error at position 15 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter 313   -- /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext 346   -- SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter 120   -- Chain processed normally 
tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext 346   -- SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter 119   -- SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: where are your full debug logs, including the request you are making, there is something you are not disclosing here. The debug logs will us what.

Comment: @Toerktumlare i have updated with the logs...

There is no body, because is a `GET`.

Response:
```{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-30T00:52:25.352+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/mywebsite/v1/something_4"
}```

Comment: dont write code in comments, its completly unreadable

Comment: Thanks @dur .... that was the issue :) ... but it wasn't because the build or restarting the IDE... Like you said, the Security Configuration wasn't loading... I didn't load the WebConfig java class..... I added it to `@Import(...)` in my service configuration and that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Security Configuration wasn't loading... I didn't load the WebConfig java class in the service..... I added it to `@Import(...)` in my service configuration and that did the trick :)